# Replace character by shell script in a file

Tags: shell, unix, replace

I have a txt file in unix that has a special character in that. 
I need to replace all instances of special characters
How can i do in shell scripting?

This is my code. I need to replace all the special characters before i sftp

```
elif [[ $module = "get_ce_xml_to_xcent" ]]
  then
    echo "get_ce_xml_to_xcent"

    ssh -T -o ConnectTimeout=5 oracle@GL-REL-CEAPP.abanet.local <<ENDSSH 
    cd /srv/exports/promotion 
    chmod 777 *.txt
sftp oracle@GL-REL-XSTAPP <<ENDFTP
cd /fileuploads/org69
mput *.txt
quit
ENDFTP
    #for i in `ls *.txt 2>/dev/null`; do echo $i; mv $i /srv/exports/promotion/arch/$i.`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"` ; done
    mv *.txt arch/
        exit
ENDSSH
```

Comment: Is it just me ? I can't see any code trying to do any kind of replacement there. What do you want to replace and by what ? what did you try so far ?

Comment: What `special character` you want to replace? Where is it in your code?

Comment: I want to replace  ‘ý’ with | sign. I cannot figure out how to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a `.txt` file containing special chars(`ý`) in multiple positions:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ cat test.txt 
"123","qweeerr","qqqqqq ý
rrrrr
hhhhhh",ý "sdfsfs"
```

You can replace `ý` from the file like below:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ sed -i 's/ý//g' test.txt 
mayankp@mayank:~/$ cat test.txt 
"123","qweeerr","qqqqqq 
rrrrr
hhhhhh", "sdfsfs"
```

You just need to append the line `sed -i 's/ý//g' test.txt` in your script before `sftp` command.

Let me know if it works.